# How do I generate inserts in sql server for a specifc where or case in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to generate inserts for a specific where or case in T-SQL without having to buy some 3rd party tool?

```
IQ     
-----------
87   - 0087
161  - 0161
205  - 0205
4087 - 4087
```

Example sproc:

```
sp_generate_insert select * from GENIUSES where IQ=161
```

Comment: `insert into yourtable (select * from geniuses where iq=161)` works as long as the table structures are the same (modify the select query if they are not).  I'm not sure what you mean by generate inserts outside of something like that.

Comment: Do you mean to generate the actual sql statements that you can then save as a script and execute on another instance?

Comment: Yes I want to generate the insert from the select statement or query for a specific where clause.

Comment: RThomas - I mean to generate text so I can execute that text like 'insert into GENIUSES (IQ) values (161)' and spit that out in the output stream.

Comment: You say you need an insert but the sample is a select. What does split that out into in the output stream mean?

Comment: Do you have to generate scripts or can you generate data? bcp.exe allows you to use a query to define the data to export, and you can use linked servers, SSIS, OPENQUERY() etc. if your goal is simply copying data from one database to another. And even if you have to buy a tool, that isn't necessarily a bad thing if it saves you time and effort.

Comment: Pondlife, I'm trying to find out if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Sql Server Management Studio you can do this:

1. Right click the database (not the table) and select tasks --> generate scripts
2. Next --> select the requested table/tables (from select specific database objects)
3. Next --> click advanced --> types of data to script = schema and data
4. Next and finish

I can't remember if during the above you can apply filters so if not you can select the table into another table and generate scripts from that other table

```
select * 
into filteredGeniuses
from GENIUSES
where IQ=161
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm very interested in a generated text example even if I first have to perform the first step. I still want to get the insert statement for just that specific case, not 500 trillion other cases. :)

Comment: Well I'm just doing a program anyway first getting an ordered list column names to generate the first part of the insert, and then just shoving hte second part for each row into a separate text insert statement.  If its an nvarchar then just sticking it in a single quotes. done and done

Comment: Sometimes building app's for your specific needs is best.